# Alter menu link path based on content type

Tags: 8, routes, navigation

I'm stumped on how to achieve this in Drupal 8 due to the removal of menu related functions. What I would like to do is check whether a menu link points to a node of content type File, and then alter the link path to point to a File field value on node (so that the menu link points to the file itself). I just need help getting to the point where I have both the path/route and the node object. I have tried to do this in `menu--main.html.twig`, where I *can* get the node id for each menu item. However there does not seem to be a way to load a node object through Twig and even if there were, I doubt this is the correct way to go about this.

I have found tutorials pointing me to implement `alterRoutes()`, for example:

```
public function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection, $provider) {
  // Find the route we want to alter
  $route = $collection->get('example.route.name');
  // Make a change to the path.
  $route->setPath('/my/new/path');
  // Re-add the collection to override the existing route.
  $collection->add('example.route.name', $route);
}
```

This doesn't seem helpful because I do *not* want to alter the route to the node whenever it is visited. I only want to alter the route when it is visited *from the menu*.

Answer (score 1):

wow I feel silly. You can still preprocess the menu template in Drupal 8. So by using `hook_preprocess_menu__main()` it looks like I will have access to everything I need and not have to do everything in the Twig template.